# Round up with ceiling in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ceil

I have to increase by 3% and round up the prices I have in a table. My script:

```
UPDATE    tbl_products
SET        Prices = CEILING(prices * 1.03, 0)
```

After I run the script, SQL Server Management Studio returns an error, saying:

> ceiling function requires one argument.

If I use `ROUND` instead of `CEILING`, the script works great. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Because `CEILING` does require one argument. Your query provides 2: [CEILING (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The error can't be much clearer. `ROUND` and `CEILING` aren't the same function, nor do they behave the same.

Comment: What's the *real* question? How to round up using a specific precision? The message is crystal clear, it's obvious that CEILING doesn't accept a precision

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is as shown below. [Ceiling()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function is used to find the smallest integer value.

```
CEILING( number )
```

Here is an example.

```
SELECT CEILING(32.65);
Result: 33

SELECT CEILING(32.1);
Result: 33

SELECT CEILING(32);
Result: 32

SELECT CEILING(-32.65);
Result: -32

SELECT CEILING(-32);
Result: -32
```